# Retriving multiple email details from gmail through java program selinium api

Tags: java, gmail

My problem is that using selenium api in java want to retrive multiple email details into java program. If i enter email count as 7 then from gmail inbox it should retrive details of 7 emails like sender subject and contents and should place properly in a collection like array list or tree map . How can i relate the different emails in gmail, is there any conncetion in any of their property?

Comment: You should use some email client. eg. `javamail` to connect to the mailbox and download messages instead of using selenium for that.

Comment: is it easy to retrive

Comment: So why do you seek help here if it is so easy?

Comment: like after getting those messages i have to write them into excel sheet using java program

Comment: I just wanted to know is it possible using selenium api?

Comment: anyone tried with selenium api